# Samsung Galaxy Ace can't connect to home wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, samsung-galaxy-ace

Any other gadget in the house can connect to the wifi except my samsung galaxy ace. It says "Connecting", then "Disconnected", then "Disabled. Secured with WPA/WPA2 PSK".  I've tried the #.#5 something solution and it doesn't make any difference. I've tried connecting with my aunt's wifi and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a logcat of the issue?

Assuming you have ADB, connect your Ace to the PC, fire up ADB, and type

```
adb start-server
adb logcat > logcat.txt
```

The issue is probably because the router is having trouble giving out addresses, but I'm not sure.